# Lower Bound Space complexity one pass algorithm / Heavy-Hitters Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am confronted with the following problem:

Let S be the family of all m-subsets of $[n] = [2m]$
let $S_1, S_2 \in S$ be distinct sets and let the state of storage be $\text{State}_1$ after stream $S_1$ is processed(resp. $\text{State}_2$)

**Show that $\text{State}_1 \ne \text{State}_2.$**

***Background*:**

- The algorithm that processes this is deterministic and that is able to solve the problem in one pass requires $\Omega(m)$ bits of storage.
- We are trying to solve the HH-Problem which is basically finding all elements in a stream that appear with a certain frequency.
- $[n]$ is defined as ${\{1,\ldots,n}\}:n\in N$
- length of each subset is m from taken from 2m

***My Ideas so far:***

- There have to be at least $\begin{pmatrix}2m \\ m \end{pmatrix}$ possible storage states
- I think you can proof this with contradiction eg. show that if $\text{State}_1 = \text{State}_2$ another condition fails but I don't know how
- My intuition tells me that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are distinct that the storage state can't be equal but I don't know how to show that.